# Powerpoint: prevent line height modification when autofitting

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

With autofit enabled, Powerpoint tries to match the size of the shape with font size and line height tuning:

[image]

Most of the time, the result is not what I want: it can even produce characters overlapping between lines! So I must make the change manually and this is very frustrating.

[image]

Is there a way to keep the autofit feature but to disable line height tuning so that only the font sized is modified?

Thanks for your help!